# Getting operational error while starting flask server

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

When i am running flask server by typing the command **python run.py**  i am getting the following error. I am using postgresql db. How to solve this?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error with connection to Postgresql. Flask app can not connect to your database with following connection string postgresql://fish:postgres@localhost:5433/exam_app. Try to connect to db with this credentional by hand, may be with PgAdmin, you will see that db does not available by this adress.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also please tell me how to connect to db with this credentials manually as i am new to flask?

Comment: I mean, try to connect to your database with any tools, for example with PgAdmin3 which is most common for postgres, when you will sure that db is available on localhost and sure in your user/pass you should make right connection string to flask variable SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI